# Cannot get request params in express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I am not able to read any req.params in my middleware. I have a minimal express web server that looks like

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//middleware
function userMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log('user came in. Hello ' + req.param('name'));
  next();
}

//register middleware
app.use('/user', userMiddleware)

// routes
app.get('/user/:name', function(req, res) {
  res.send('username : ' + req.params.name);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("listening on 3000...");
```

When I try to hit localhost:3000/user/williams , I expect to see  in the log :

```
user came in. Hello williams
```

but I see

```
user came in. Hello undefined
```

Should I include any other middleware so that the req.params is populated  in the middleware ? 
I'm using  `express@3.3.4`

Comment: related GH issue : https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2088

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `app.param()` is unconventional in this case and not really intuitive. Since I already had the function representing the middleware, I could do :

```
//middleware
function userMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log('user came in. Hello ' + req.params.name);
  next();
}

// routes
app.get('/user/:name', userMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  res.send('username : ' + req.params.name);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

My answer below is incorrect. You don't actually need `json` or `urlencoded` middleware to get route params - they're only needed for `req.query` and `req.body` to work. As you're aware (since you're one of the posters there), the link you provided in your comment describes the issue:

https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2088

The problem is that you are trying to access route parameters before they exist - middleware runs before routes do. One solution would be to use `app.param()` as suggested in that link (instead of your `userMiddleware`):

```
app.param('name', function(req, res, next, name) {
    console.log('user came in. Hello ' + name);
    next();
});
```

Note that this will find `name` parameters in ALL routes so you might want to name the parameter something a bit more specific, like `username`. You could also check the beginning of `req.url` if you wanted to narrow it down that way.

BTW Using `req.param()` as you did in your original code should generally be avoided; to quote from the Express docs: `Direct access to req.body, req.params, and req.query should be favoured for clarity - unless you truly accept input from each object.`

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Leaving it here since it contains info that might be useful in other situations...

I believe you need to add this middleware in order to have GET and POST variables available:

```
.use(express.json()) //support JSON-encoded bodies
.use(express.urlencoded()) //support URL-encoded bodies
```

And:

```
.use(express.methodOverride())
```

If you also have a need for HTTP verbs such as PUT or DELETE in all browsers.

Instead of `json` and `urlencoded`, you *could* just use `bodyparser`, but that would be a security vulnerability due to file uploads. See http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html. Also, `bodyparser` is deprecated in Express 4. Note that if you want to support file uploads you'll need to use additional middleware for that (a good option is https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer).

Comment: I tried using those middlewares. But they do nothing to populate the req.params object.

Comment: I updated my answer, which you provides a bit more description of the solution than on GitHub, in case it's helpful to you or future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have come across is to use a router with an `all` method.

For example:

```
function middleware(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Parameters - ', req.params)
}

let router = require('express').Router
router.route('/test')
   .all(middleware)
   .get((req, res, next) => {
     // handle route
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I know this question is old but here is my way to solve it in the prtesent

const {Router}=require("express");
const router = Router();

const middlewareExample = require("archiveExample.js");

router.put("/example/:id", 
  (req,res,next)=>{res.locals.params=req.params; next();},
  middlewareExample,
  async(req,res)=>{
  //Some code...
});

//Now you have req.params in res.locals.params
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

in such case, the req will not be having anything in the params object. You might want to split the url like this.

```
const myMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // Extracting URL parameters manually
  const urlParts = req.url.split('/');
  const myParamIndex = urlParts.indexOf('myRoute') + 1;

  // Check if the parameter exists in the URL
  if (myParamIndex !== 0 && myParamIndex < urlParts.length) {
    const myParam = urlParts[myParamIndex];
    console.log('Middleware - myParam:', myParam);
  }

  // Continue to the next middleware or route handler
  next();
};
```