# Log any path parameter in any path in Express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

Consider following express application:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params); // Logs {}
  next();
});

app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send({id: req.params.id})
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Why the middleware does not have access to path parameters? I want to have a middleware that logs every path parameter of any path in an Express application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get request params in express middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319731/cannot-get-request-params-in-express-middleware)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your middleware function has no url associated with it, so it will get a default url - `'/'`. And in that url there aren't any path params.

You have to use your function as a middleware for every url you define. Something like this:

```
function logger(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.params); 
   next();        
}

app.get('/:id', logger, function(req, res) {
  res.send({id: req.params.id})
});
```

Comment: What if I want to call `logger` on all paths?

Comment: @Mohsen see my answer below, you can call 'logger' on all routes as long as they pass the 'id' parameter in the path (if you use the suggested approach below). `app.param('id', ANY FUNCTION);` would run `ANY FUNCTION` every time that any path came with an 'id' param.

Answer (score 0):

Though the way suggested by @Николай Караджов will work, there is a more 'express-way' to do this. See below for code and explanation.

```
function extractParams(req, res, next, id) {
  req.id = id;
  next();    
}

app.param('id', extractParams);

app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send({id: req.id});
});
```

Express provides a `param` method on your express app that will 'intercept' any matched parameter on request ('id') and run the provided middleware routine (`extractParams` in our case).

Do whatever you need to do with your request parameter within the `extractParams` middleware — we are just attaching the id parameter to the request object with whatever key we desire ('id').

We can then trigger the next route handler (`next()`).

So, in your `app.get('/:id')` callback function, you can just access the 'id' directly from the request object because you attached it in your middleware before you even got to this route handler. This can be very powerful if you need to do a lot to your params before passing along info to the next function.

**EDIT**: per your clarification comments, try the following, which will match whatever param comes in and then log it out in the handler.

```
app.get('/^(.*)$/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params[0]);
});
```

Comment: I want to log any path parameter in any path.

Comment: You will need to listen on a wildcard param '*' and then extract the given param from the request (my answer and @Николай Караджов's answer offer possible options). You can then log that param. Keep in mind that nested paths '/path/:anyparam/etc.' will require special handling.

Comment: I don't have access to routes. I'm writing a module that I can use as a connect middleware that logs all path parameters on all paths.

Comment: @Mohsen, how are you planning on 'injecting' the middleware logger? Are you extending express? Are you adding the logger as a configuration? Need more details to answer the question given that the constraints about this being a third-party library wasn't upfront in the initial question.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the middleware is provided by a third-party or not. I want to use `app.use()` and log all path params on all paths

Comment: It does matter @Mohsen. If you would like to DM me for further help, feel free.